# map dictionary property petapoco

Tags: c#, poco, petapoco

I have a model that has a dictionary as one its properties

```
public class PupilCache {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; } 
}
```

The keys for this dictionary are all columns for a joining table in SQL. Is it possible with peta poco to retrieve this in one query?

Answer (score 0):

PetaPoco maintainer here. Yes this should be possible using the fetch method for which you provide a callback to populate the Poco relationship. You will however be required to supply a Poco so that PetaPoco can map the Key Value columns from the DB to a Poco (required).

See this

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Perform a multi-poco fetch
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">The first POCO type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T2">The second POCO type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TRet">The returned list POCO type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="cb">A callback function to connect the POCO instances, or null to automatically guess the relationships</param>
    /// <param name="sql">The SQL query to be executed</param>
    /// <param name="args">Arguments to any embedded parameters in the SQL</param>
    /// <returns>A collection of POCO's as a List</returns>
    List<TRet> Fetch<T1, T2, TRet>(Func<T1, T2, TRet> cb, string sql, params object[] args);
```

Example

```
db.Fetch<PupilCache, KeyValuePoco, PupilCache>((pc, kv) => pc.Properties.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value), "query");
```